# Howto convert CefSharp 3 ZoomLevel to percentage and back again

Tags: c#, browser, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

The CefSharp Browser methods: SetZoomLevel and GetZoomLevelAsync use the ZoomLevel which is hard for humans to understand: https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11491#p21763

Sample values:

```
150% = Browser.SetZoomLevel(2.2239010857415451);
125% = Browser.SetZoomLevel(1.2239010857415449);
 75% = Browser.SetZoomLevel(-1.5778829311823859);
```

1. Is there an easy way to calculate the ZoomLevel  by a give %?
2. Is there an easy way to calculate the % from the ZoomLevel to show the user the current % the browser window?

Comment: What is your question about?

Comment: I have edited the question, maybe its clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class CefExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the given percentage to the ZoomLevel to looke like chrome at zooming in/out
    /// 100 (%) = No Zoom / Reset
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pPercentage">Default= 100 = reset zoom</param>
    public static void SetZoomPercent(this ChromiumWebBrowser pBrowser, int pPercentage = 100)
    {
        var lTmp = pPercentage / 100f;
        var lZoomLevel = Math.Log(lTmp, 1.2);
        pBrowser.SetZoomLevel(lZoomLevel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Translates the cef ZoomLevel to the Zoom showed at the Chrome Browser
    /// Usage: Browser.GetZoomPercentAsync().Result
    ///</summary>
    public static async Task<double> GetZoomPercentAsync(this ChromiumWebBrowser pBrowser)
    {
        var lZoomLevel = await pBrowser.GetZoomLevelAsync();
        var lPercentage = Math.Pow(1.2, lZoomLevel) * 100;
        return lPercentage;

    }
}
```